# Is DLR project dead?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-language-runtime

I was thinking of using [.NET DLR](http://dlr.codeplex.com/) for a project , but I see it hasn't changed since 2010. Does anyone know if this project will be maintained or if it has been superseded by anything else? I am afraid to start a project that heavily depends on the DLR if DLR is no longer supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It got integrated into .net in version 4.0 in April 2010. As such, the DLR project itself isn't updated anymore. The msdn has a good overview: [Dynamic Language Runtime Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx).

Comment: oh, I didn't realize that. I don't see any Microsoft.Scripting.* dll  Has this been changed?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't really worked with it. I added a link in my post to he DLR overview in msdn.